# iOS perform LDAP search

Tags: iphone, ios, ldap

Hi I'm trying to integrate an LDAP search functionality into my app similar to the one the iPhone has under Mail, contacts, Calendar.

I did some google searches but I'm quiet lost. Can anyone point me in the right direction to implement this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab OpenLDAP for iOS from [here](https://github.com/bindle/iOSPorts). You can find OpenLDAP tutorials [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialLDAP-SoftwareDevelopment.html).